# Countdown in seconds: milliseconds

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

I need a div's text to turn red when you start counting, it should lasts 3 seconds and leave the red text while counting. Then return back to normal when it finishes (and regular displays when stopped 3 seconds)
Displaying the count in milliseconds.

I tried, but it still fails.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you post the code you used?

Comment: What do you mean "When you start counting"?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

function startCountDown(ele) {
    ele.origText = ele.innerHTML;
    ele.style.color = "red";
    ele.timeStart = (new Date()).getTime() + 3000;
    ele.intervalVar = setInterval(function() {
        var curTime = ele.timeStart - (new Date()).getTime();
        if(curTime < 0) {
            ele.innerHTML = ele.origText;
            ele.style.color = "";
            clearInterval(ele.intervalVar);
        }
        else ele.innerHTML = curTime;
        
    },20);
    
}

setTimeout(function() {startCountDown(foo);},1000);
```

```html
<div id = 'foo'>bar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Innovative/Alternative** way to show timers using `requestAnimationFrame`,

http://jsfiddle.net/wjtkr95t/4/

wich has less impact to the browser's memory.It also allows you with some minor modifications to have more control over timers,animations ... whatever...

```
var
end,
now=Date.now,
raf=window.requestAnimationFrame,
duration=120000,//MS
out=document.getElementById('out');

function displayTime(){
 var c=end-now();
 out.textContent=ms2TimeString(c>0?(raf(displayTime),c):0);
}
function go(){
 end=now()+duration;
 raf(displayTime);
}
```

Ms to timeString function

```
function ms2TimeString(a,k,s,m,h){
 return k=a%1e3,
  s=a/1e3%60|0,
  m=a/6e4%60|0,
  h=a/36e5%24|0,
  (h?(h<10?'0'+h:h)+':':'')+
  (m<10?0:'')+m+':'+
  (s<10?0:'')+s+'.'+
  (k<100?k<10?'00':0:'')+k
}
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/45335/33435

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/wjtkr95t/

**DEMO (change the color)** .. only 100ms.. change it

http://jsfiddle.net/wjtkr95t/1/

**DEMO (change the color after 2 sec)** .. only 100ms.. change it

http://jsfiddle.net/wjtkr95t/2/

**DEMO (change the color after 2 sec with 700ms color animation)**

http://jsfiddle.net/wjtkr95t/3/

if you have any questions just ask

Answer (score 0):

I think if you show us your algorithm it would be clearer for anyone who want to help you. Waiting it, I would recommend you to see how the function `setInterval()` works, because it puts a delay so you probably would use it to reach your goal.

Go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to see docs.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using CSS animations, and adding a class to a div element.

This method would be better, since CSS animations are not blocking, whereas since javascript is single synchronous thread (for the most part); and so using setInterval will block the rest of the javascript from functioning.